# Ray Tensorflow-gpu 2.0 RecursionError

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, ray

**System information**

OS Platform and Distribution (e.g., Linux Ubuntu 16.04): Ubuntu 18.04

Ray installed from (source or binary): binary

Ray version: 0.7.3

Python version: 3.7

Tensorflow version: tensorflow-gpu 2.0.0rc0

Exact command to reproduce:

```
# Importing packages
from time import time
import gym
import tensorflow as tf
import ray

# Creating our initial model    
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, input_shape=(24,), activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='softmax')
        ])

# Setting parameters
episodes = 64
env_name = 'BipedalWalker-v2'

# Initializing ray
ray.init(num_cpus=8, num_gpus=1)

# Creating our ray function
@ray.remote
def play(weights):
    actor = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, input_shape=(24,), activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='softmax')
        ])
    actor = actor.set_weights(weights)
    env = gym.make('BipedalWalker-v2').env
    env._max_episode_steps=1e20
    obs = env.reset()
    for _ in range(1200):
        action = actor.predict_classes(obs).flatten()[0]
        action = env.action_space.sample()
        obs, rt, done, info = env.step(action)
    return rt

# Testing ray
start = time()
weights = model.get_weights()
weights = ray.put(weights)
results = ray.get([play.remote(weights) for i in range(episodes)])
ray.shutdown()
print('Ray done after:',time()-start)
```

**Describe the problem**

I am trying to use Ray to parallelize rollouts of OpenAI gym environments using a Tensorflow 2.0-gpu Keras actor. Every time I try to instantiate a Keras model using @ray.remote it raises a recursion depth reached error. I am following the documentation outlined by Ray, where it is suggested to pass weights instead of models. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here, any thoughts?

**Source code / logs**

File "/home/jacob/anaconda3/envs/tf-2.0-gpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/init.py", line 50, in getattr
module = self._load()

File "/home/jacob/anaconda3/envs/tf-2.0-gpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/init.py", line 44, in _load
module = _importlib.import_module(self.name)

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Comment: One comment is that the issue is not specific to `tensorflow-gpu`. I reproduced it with just `tensorflow`.

Comment: I filed https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/32159.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the GitHub response to this issue: https://github.com/ray-project/ray/issues/5614

All that needs to be done is import tensorflow in the function definition:

```
@ray.remote
def play(weights):
    import tensorflow as tf
    actor = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, input_shape=(24,), activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='softmax')
        ])
    actor.set_weights(weights)
    env = gym.make('BipedalWalker-v2').env
    env._max_episode_steps=1e20
    obs = env.reset()
    for _ in range(1200):
        action = actor.predict_classes(np.array([obs])).flatten()[0]
        action = env.action_space.sample()
        obs, rt, done, info = env.step(action)
    return rt
```

Answer (score 1):

The core problem appears to be that cloudpickle (which Ray uses to serialize remote functions and ship them to the worker processes) isn't able to pickle the `tf.keras.Sequential` class. For example, I can reproduce the issue as follows

```
import cloudpickle  # cloudpickle.__version__ == '1.2.1'
import tensorflow as tf  # tf.__version__ == '2.0.0-rc0'

def f():
    tf.keras.Sequential

cloudpickle.loads(cloudpickle.dumps(f))  # This fails.
```

The last line fails with

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RecursionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-25cc307e6227> in <module>
----> 1 cloudpickle.loads(cloudpickle.dumps(f))

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py in __getattr__(self, item)
     48 
     49   def __getattr__(self, item):
---> 50     module = self._load()
     51     return getattr(module, item)
     52 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py in _load(self)
     42   def _load(self):
     43     """Import the target module and insert it into the parent's namespace."""
---> 44     module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
     45     self._parent_module_globals[self._local_name] = module
     46     self.__dict__.update(module.__dict__)

... last 2 frames repeated, from the frame below ...

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py in __getattr__(self, item)
     48 
     49   def __getattr__(self, item):
---> 50     module = self._load()
     51     return getattr(module, item)
     52 

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Interestingly, this **succeeds** with `tensorflow==1.14.0`, but I imagine keras has changed a ton in 2.0.

### Workaround

As a **workaround**, you can try defining `f` in a separate module or Python file like

```
# helper_file.py

import tensorflow as tf

def f():
    tf.keras.Sequential
```

And then use it in your main script as follows.

```
import helper_file
import ray

ray.init(num_cpus=1)

@ray.remote
def use_f():
    helper_file.f()

ray.get(use_f.remote())
```

The difference here is that when cloudpickle tries to serialize `use_f`, it won't actually look at the contents of `helper_file`. When some worker process tries to deserialize `use_f`, that worker process will import `helper_file`. This extra indirection seems to cause cloudpickle to work more reliably. This is the same thing that happens when you pickle a function using tensorflow or any library. Cloudpickle doesn't serialize the whole library, it just tells the deserializing process to import the relevant library.

**Note:** For this to work on multiple machines, `helper_file.py` must exist and be on the Python path on each machine (one way to accomplish this is by installing it as a Python module on each machine).

I verified that this seems to address the issue in your example. After making that fix, I ran into

```
  File "<ipython-input-4-bb51dc74442c>", line 3, in play
  File "/Users/rkn/Workspace/ray/helper_file.py", line 15, in play
    action = actor.predict_classes(obs).flatten()[0]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'predict_classes'
```

but that looks like a separate issue.